# I am trying to find most popular item in my tables using sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite, count, max

Hi everybody I seem to be stuck and I hope you guys can help me out here. I am trying write a code that will only display the most ordered food item and how many times its been ordered without adding like where Quantity > 5 or something to that. I just want to the code to give me the most ordered item by itself I have these tables:

ROOMSERVICE

- RoomServiceNumber (Primary Key) Type: Integer
- OrderNumber Type: Integer
- GuestID     Type: Integer
- Date Type: DateTime
- Time Type: DateTime
- TotalPrice Type: Integer

RSLINEITEM

- OrderNumber (Primary Key) Type: Integer
- ItemNumber Type: Integer
- Quantity Type: Integer

ITEM

- ItemNumber (Primary Key) Type: Integer
- Description Type: Text
- Price Type: Integer

So far I've gotten my sql code to show me all the items(Description) and the number of items its been ordered. I only want the most ordered item.

My code:

```
SELECT Description, SUM(Quantity) AS NumberofTimesOrdered
FROM RSLINEITEM JOIN ITEM ON (RSLINEITEM.ItemNumber=ITEM.ItemNumber)
GROUP BY Description
```

My Reults are:

```
   Description       NumberofTimesOrdered
   Baked Potato      1
   Bud Light Bottle  2
   French Fries      1
   Heineken Bottle   2
   Large Coke        1
   Large Sprite      3
   Pork Cutlet       4
   Prime Rib         6
   Orange Juice      1
```

I only want my code to only show me something  like this:

```
   Description       NumberofTimesOrdered
   Prime Rib         6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`.

```
SELECT Description
      ,SUM(Quantity) AS NumberofTimesOrdered
FROM   RSLINEITEM
JOIN   ITEM USING (ItemNumber)
GROUP  BY Description 
ORDER  BY 2 DESC
LIMIT  1
```

You can repeat the expression in the ORDER BY clause or use the ordinal number. [The manual about that](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html):

> If the ORDER BY expression is a constant integer K then the expression
>   is considered an alias for the K-th column of the result set (columns
>   are numbered from left to right starting with 1).

I also simplified the code with `USING`. [Info at the same source](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html).